# Close menu on X click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am struggling to get the X to remove the active state class of the Menu and return it to a 'hidden' state. Where am I going wrong in the JS? 
When the Menu button is clicked the Menu appears but when the X is clicked nothing happens. How would I return it to its hidden state of 0% width?

The JS is where I am getting confused. Would I need to use a different method? or am I needing an *if* statement there to determine when the active class is applied?

```js
const menuArrive = () => {
    const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const cross = document.querySelector('.cross');
    const menuActive = document.querySelector('.menuactive');

    menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.add('menuactive');
    });
    cross.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menuActive.classList.remove('menuactive');
    });
}
menuArrive();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
}

body {
    height               : 100vh;
    overflow-x           : hidden;
    margin               : 0;
    font-family          : 'Lustria', sans-serif;
    display              : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows   : 10% 45% 45%;
    grid-template-areas  :
        "header  section"
        "main    section"
        "main    footer";
}

/* Header */
header {
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items    : center;
    grid-area      : header;
    background     : #FDBC58;
    padding        : 6px;
}

p,
.fa-bars,
.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding    : 0;
    margin     : 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    font-size: 14px;
    color    : black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : black;
}

.burger {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width           : 20px;
    height          : 2px;
    margin          : 5px;
    transition      : all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Left Section */

main {
    grid-area: main;
    position : relative;
}

main img {
    height    : 100%;
    width     : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.menu-btn {
    z-index      : 4;
    position     : absolute;
    top          : 50%;
    left         : 50%;
    transform    : translate(-50%, -50%);
    width        : 50%;
    height       : 50px;
    border       : white solid 5px;
    background   : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color        : white;
    font-size    : 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor       : pointer;
}

.menu {
    height: 60%;
    /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
    /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: absolute;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    text-align     : center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.textcontain {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.textcontain h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin   : 10px 0;
}

.textcontain p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.cross {
    display   : block;
    width     : 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position  : absolute;
    top       : 2%;
    right     : 3%;
    cursor    : pointer;
}

/* When menu button is clicked */
.menuactive {
    height          : 60%;
    width           : 40%;
    position        : absolute;
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s ease-in;
    display         : flex;
    flex-direction  : column;
    text-align      : center;
    justify-content : center;
}
.menu-hidden {
    display: none;
}
/* slide in links */
.sidenav {
    height          : 95%;
    width           : 0;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 1;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding        : 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size      : 25px;
    color          : #000;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    transition     : 0.3s;
}

.sidenav-active {
    height          : 90%;
    width           : 13%;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 8;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;

}

/* Top right area */
section {
    grid-area: section;
}

section img {
    width     : 100%;
    height    : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* Bottom right area */
footer {
    grid-area      : footer;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}

img {
    height    : 250px;
    width     : 230px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#flag {
    height       : 20px;
    width        : 30px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;

}

/* Resonsive */
@media only screen and (max-width:996px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    main {
        grid-area: main;

    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 20%;
    }
}

/* Resonsive */

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 40%;
    }

    .sidenav-active {
        height          : 90%;
        width           : 100%;
        position        : fixed;
        z-index         : 1;
        bottom          : 0;
        left            : 0;
        background-color: #FDBC58;
        overflow-x      : hidden;
        padding-top     : 20px;
        transition      : 0.5s;
        align-items     : center;
        text-align      : centerx;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin   : 0;
    }

    header p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .fa-facebook .fa-instagram {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin   : 0 5ox;
    }

    header p {
        font-size : 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .burger div {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width           : 15px;
        height          : 2px;
        margin          : 3px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Julie's Kopitiam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="julies.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4612429e8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lustria&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <h2>julie's kopitiam</h2>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/julieskopitiam/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/julieskopitiam/?hl=en" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Julie's+Kopitiam/@55.8306567,-4.2802888,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xafb9cc150cb13d58?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0i9OgxdHnAhXinVwKHcFBCQYQ_BIwCnoECA8QCA"
            target="_blank">
            <p>1109 Pollokshaws Road, G41 3YG Glasgow</p>
        </a>
    </header>
    <main>
        <img src="83090476_1616376001834909_1775866941357948928_o.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-btn">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="cross">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="textcontain">
                <h4>Starters</h4>
                <p>Pickled Cucumber</p>
                <p>Chilli Chicken</p>
                <h4>Mains</h4>
                <p>Nasi Goreng</p>
                <p>Pulled Pork</p>
                <p>Shrimp Curry</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </main>
    <section>
        <img src="23754760_1006631889475993_3268080554873666870_n.jpg" alt="">
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="imagecontain">
            <img src="/82637280_1606280486177794_2225049443105767424_n.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img id="flag" src="/118-malasya copy.svg" alt="">
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little mistake, in the cross event listener it should be:

```
menu.classList.remove('menuactive');
```

instead of `menuActive.classList.remove('menuactive');`

As you want to change the class of the `.menu` element.

```js
const menuArrive = () => {
    const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const cross = document.querySelector('.cross');
    const menuActive = document.querySelector('.menuactive');

    menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.add('menuactive');
    });
    cross.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.remove('menuactive');
    });
}
menuArrive();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
}

body {
    height               : 100vh;
    overflow-x           : hidden;
    margin               : 0;
    font-family          : 'Lustria', sans-serif;
    display              : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows   : 10% 45% 45%;
    grid-template-areas  :
        "header  section"
        "main    section"
        "main    footer";
}

/* Header */
header {
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items    : center;
    grid-area      : header;
    background     : #FDBC58;
    padding        : 6px;
}

p,
.fa-bars,
.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding    : 0;
    margin     : 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    font-size: 14px;
    color    : black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : black;
}

.burger {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width           : 20px;
    height          : 2px;
    margin          : 5px;
    transition      : all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Left Section */

main {
    grid-area: main;
    position : relative;
}

main img {
    height    : 100%;
    width     : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.menu-btn {
    z-index      : 4;
    position     : absolute;
    top          : 50%;
    left         : 50%;
    transform    : translate(-50%, -50%);
    width        : 50%;
    height       : 50px;
    border       : white solid 5px;
    background   : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color        : white;
    font-size    : 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor       : pointer;
}

.menu {
    height: 60%;
    /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
    /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: absolute;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    text-align     : center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.textcontain {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.textcontain h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin   : 10px 0;
}

.textcontain p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.cross {
    display   : block;
    width     : 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position  : absolute;
    top       : 2%;
    right     : 3%;
    cursor    : pointer;
}

/* When menu button is clicked */
.menuactive {
    height          : 60%;
    width           : 40%;
    position        : absolute;
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s ease-in;
    display         : flex;
    flex-direction  : column;
    text-align      : center;
    justify-content : center;
}
.menu-hidden {
    display: none;
}
/* slide in links */
.sidenav {
    height          : 95%;
    width           : 0;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 1;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding        : 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size      : 25px;
    color          : #000;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    transition     : 0.3s;
}

.sidenav-active {
    height          : 90%;
    width           : 13%;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 8;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;

}

/* Top right area */
section {
    grid-area: section;
}

section img {
    width     : 100%;
    height    : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* Bottom right area */
footer {
    grid-area      : footer;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}

img {
    height    : 250px;
    width     : 230px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#flag {
    height       : 20px;
    width        : 30px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;

}

/* Resonsive */
@media only screen and (max-width:996px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    main {
        grid-area: main;

    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 20%;
    }
}

/* Resonsive */

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 40%;
    }

    .sidenav-active {
        height          : 90%;
        width           : 100%;
        position        : fixed;
        z-index         : 1;
        bottom          : 0;
        left            : 0;
        background-color: #FDBC58;
        overflow-x      : hidden;
        padding-top     : 20px;
        transition      : 0.5s;
        align-items     : center;
        text-align      : centerx;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin   : 0;
    }

    header p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .fa-facebook .fa-instagram {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin   : 0 5ox;
    }

    header p {
        font-size : 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .burger div {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width           : 15px;
        height          : 2px;
        margin          : 3px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Julie's Kopitiam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="julies.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4612429e8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lustria&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <h2>julie's kopitiam</h2>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/julieskopitiam/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/julieskopitiam/?hl=en" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Julie's+Kopitiam/@55.8306567,-4.2802888,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xafb9cc150cb13d58?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0i9OgxdHnAhXinVwKHcFBCQYQ_BIwCnoECA8QCA"
            target="_blank">
            <p>1109 Pollokshaws Road, G41 3YG Glasgow</p>
        </a>
    </header>
    <main>
        <img src="83090476_1616376001834909_1775866941357948928_o.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-btn">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="cross">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="textcontain">
                <h4>Starters</h4>
                <p>Pickled Cucumber</p>
                <p>Chilli Chicken</p>
                <h4>Mains</h4>
                <p>Nasi Goreng</p>
                <p>Pulled Pork</p>
                <p>Shrimp Curry</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </main>
    <section>
        <img src="23754760_1006631889475993_3268080554873666870_n.jpg" alt="">
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="imagecontain">
            <img src="/82637280_1606280486177794_2225049443105767424_n.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img id="flag" src="/118-malasya copy.svg" alt="">
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

```
menuActive.classList.remove('menuactive');
```

to

```
menu.classList.remove('menuactive');
```

```js
const menuArrive = () => {
    const menuButton = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const cross = document.querySelector('.cross');
    const menuActive = document.querySelector('.menuactive');

    menuButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        menu.classList.add('menuactive');
    });
    cross.addEventListener('click', () => {
          menu.classList.remove('menuactive');
    });
}
menuArrive();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
}

body {
    height               : 100vh;
    overflow-x           : hidden;
    margin               : 0;
    font-family          : 'Lustria', sans-serif;
    display              : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows   : 10% 45% 45%;
    grid-template-areas  :
        "header  section"
        "main    section"
        "main    footer";
}

/* Header */
header {
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items    : center;
    grid-area      : header;
    background     : #FDBC58;
    padding        : 6px;
}

p,
.fa-bars,
.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    margin: 0;
}

h2 {
    padding    : 0;
    margin     : 0;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-facebook,
.fa-instagram {
    font-size: 14px;
    color    : black;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color          : black;
}

.burger {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width           : 20px;
    height          : 2px;
    margin          : 5px;
    transition      : all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Left Section */

main {
    grid-area: main;
    position : relative;
}

main img {
    height    : 100%;
    width     : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.menu-btn {
    z-index      : 4;
    position     : absolute;
    top          : 50%;
    left         : 50%;
    transform    : translate(-50%, -50%);
    width        : 50%;
    height       : 50px;
    border       : white solid 5px;
    background   : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color        : white;
    font-size    : 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor       : pointer;
}

.menu {
    height: 60%;
    /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
    /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: absolute;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s ease-in;
    /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    text-align     : center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.textcontain {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.textcontain h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin   : 10px 0;
}

.textcontain p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.cross {
    display   : block;
    width     : 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position  : absolute;
    top       : 2%;
    right     : 3%;
    cursor    : pointer;
}

/* When menu button is clicked */
.menuactive {
    height          : 60%;
    width           : 40%;
    position        : absolute;
    z-index         : 6;
    left            : 50%;
    top             : 50%;
    transform       : translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    box-shadow      : 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s ease-in;
    display         : flex;
    flex-direction  : column;
    text-align      : center;
    justify-content : center;
}
.menu-hidden {
    display: none;
}
/* slide in links */
.sidenav {
    height          : 95%;
    width           : 0;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 1;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding        : 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size      : 25px;
    color          : #000;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    transition     : 0.3s;
}

.sidenav-active {
    height          : 90%;
    width           : 13%;
    position        : fixed;
    z-index         : 8;
    bottom          : 0;
    left            : 0;
    background-color: #FDBC58;
    overflow-x      : hidden;
    padding-top     : 20px;
    transition      : 0.5s;

}

/* Top right area */
section {
    grid-area: section;
}

section img {
    width     : 100%;
    height    : 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* Bottom right area */
footer {
    grid-area      : footer;
    display        : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items    : center;
}

img {
    height    : 250px;
    width     : 230px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

#flag {
    height       : 20px;
    width        : 30px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;

}

/* Resonsive */
@media only screen and (max-width:996px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    main {
        grid-area: main;

    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 20%;
    }
}

/* Resonsive */

@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    body {
        height               : 100vh;
        margin               : 0;
        display              : grid;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows   : repeat(auto, 4);
        grid-template-areas  :
            "header"
            "main"
            "section"
            "footer";
    }

    main img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 100%;
    }

    section {
        grid-area: section;
    }

    section img {
        object-fit     : cover;
        object-position: 100% 40%;
    }

    .sidenav-active {
        height          : 90%;
        width           : 100%;
        position        : fixed;
        z-index         : 1;
        bottom          : 0;
        left            : 0;
        background-color: #FDBC58;
        overflow-x      : hidden;
        padding-top     : 20px;
        transition      : 0.5s;
        align-items     : center;
        text-align      : centerx;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin   : 0;
    }

    header p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .fa-facebook .fa-instagram {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    header h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin   : 0 5ox;
    }

    header p {
        font-size : 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .fa-facebook {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .burger div {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        width           : 15px;
        height          : 2px;
        margin          : 3px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Julie's Kopitiam</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="julies.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4612429e8e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lustria&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <h2>julie's kopitiam</h2>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/julieskopitiam/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/julieskopitiam/?hl=en" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Julie's+Kopitiam/@55.8306567,-4.2802888,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xafb9cc150cb13d58?sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0i9OgxdHnAhXinVwKHcFBCQYQ_BIwCnoECA8QCA"
            target="_blank">
            <p>1109 Pollokshaws Road, G41 3YG Glasgow</p>
        </a>
    </header>
    <main>
        <img src="83090476_1616376001834909_1775866941357948928_o.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="#">Clients</a>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="menu-btn">Menu</button>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="cross">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="textcontain">
                <h4>Starters</h4>
                <p>Pickled Cucumber</p>
                <p>Chilli Chicken</p>
                <h4>Mains</h4>
                <p>Nasi Goreng</p>
                <p>Pulled Pork</p>
                <p>Shrimp Curry</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </main>
    <section>
        <img src="23754760_1006631889475993_3268080554873666870_n.jpg" alt="">
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="imagecontain">
            <img src="/82637280_1606280486177794_2225049443105767424_n.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img id="flag" src="/118-malasya copy.svg" alt="">
    </footer>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.